# In Google script is there a way to reference a specific sheet instead of the active sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

Is there a way to have scripts/macros run on a specific sheet instead of the active sheet?

In my trix, i want my first tab to always be updated with the data from my calendar. [The script works](https://www.cloudbakers.com/blog/export-google-calendar-entries-to-a-google-spreadsheet), but it only updates the active sheet, not the first tab. I am also trying to make a macro to copy that first tab but i can't find a way to reference the first tab, only the active sheet. Help?

```
    function CopyAllDataTab() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
};
```

Comment: Please show your research effort. Have you reviewed all the methods available to the Spreadsheet class?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the name of the sheet? If the sheet name stays the same, you can call the sheet by saying:

```
function CopyAllDataTab() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Name of the sheet")
      sheet.getRange('A1').activate();
      sheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
    };
```